# Google Data Studio is throwing an internal server error when trying to fetch data

Tags: looker-studio

After adding my custom connector to google data studio, when I try to create a graph it throws an internal server error with no explanation. I am wondering if anyone else has an idea of possible causes.

I have already tried making sure that there are no special characters (1-9, a-z, A-Z only), whitelisting my domain, reducing to data to 1 row and testing on a different table. Below is my code to create the schema.

```
var fields = cc.getFields();
var types = cc.FieldType;

metadata = cube.getMetadata();
var dimens = metadata.dimensions;

dimens.forEach(function(dim) {
    dim.hierarchies.forEach(function(arch) {
        arch.levels.forEach(function(level) {
            if (level.LEVEL_NAME != "(All)") 
                fields.newDimension()
                .setId(level.LEVEL_UNIQUE_NAME)
                .setName(level.LEVEL_NAME)
                .setDescription(level.LEVEL_CAPTION)
                .setType(types.TEXT)
.setGroup(level.HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME.substring(level.HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME.indexOf('.') + 1));
        }
      });
    });
  });

var metrics = metadata.measures;

metrics.forEach(function(met) {    
   fields.newMetric()
   .setId(met.MEASURE_UNIQUE_NAME)
   .setName(met.MEASURE_NAME)
   .setType(types.NUMBER)
});

sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1).setBackground("LimeGreen");
return fields;
```

System Error:

Data Studio has encountered a system error.

Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Error ID: a933d9a9

Inside the actual packet it is code: 13, reason "INTERNAL"

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the system still didn't like my id's despite my modifications, by just numbering the columns I was able to get it to connect.